# Updating ECS Service does not update API gateway deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, cloud, aws-api-gateway, amazon-ecs

Simply put, these are the steps I've used to get a private ECS deployment up and running.

1. Create ECS Deploy, VPC and LB
2. Create VPC Link - choose private VPC and private subnet
3. Create HTTP API on API Gateway
4. Create a route - Choose api -> Routes -> Create -> Method (any) -> path: /{proxy+}
5. Create integration - choose api -> Manage integrations -> Private Resource -> ALB -> VPC Link

When I use github actions to update my taskdef/service, I see the deployment is successful, but the API gateway url still points to the last image used. This is weird because when I check out the service I can see it is mapped to the same loadbalancer - so the question is; why aren't changes being reflected on API Gateway?

Comment: "but the API gateway url still points to the last image used" that statement makes no sense. API Gateway doesn't forward (point to) a docker image, it points to a URL, in this case your ALB URL. Are you sure the deployment has completed, and all previous ECS tasks have been deregistered, before you test?